# Android camera preview with filter using SurfaceView

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, camera, surfaceview

My problem is this:
I have a seperate class which extends SurfaceView and my main activity has this view.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback
```

I take camera preview's copy data from onPreviewFrame method, and save it to a Bitmap object, and this Bitmap object is used in onDraw method.

I set a flag to understand if the Bitmap is ready or not, onPreviewFrame makes the Bitmap ready, and onDraw takes this Bitmap and draws on the canvas.

But the problem is, I want to filter this Bitmap image, but even with no filter I get 5-10 fps with LG G4 device.

What should I do to improve performance? At this moment I haven't used any AsyncTask or Threads, but I'm not sure those alone will be enough.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I also get this warning on Android Studio.

Comment: What kind of filter do you need? Why do you need this (very inefficient) route of convert to bitmap and draw on a separate request? Maybe using camera native texture will be enough? This approach can give you full frame rate with minimal CPU load

Comment: I want filters like histogram equalization, then apply some constant RGB values to the pixels. I tried this on my computer with Java, it wasn't really slow. What do you mean by camera native texture? The TextureSurface class?

Comment: Demo of GPU-based approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: Using Bitmaps is a big overhead. You should apply filters without conversation to Bitmap. But may be you don't know how to draw filtered frame on the screen without using bitmaps? Then you should look at this project: https://github.com/google/grafika . It contains such use case. Also you may have to use OpenGL to get maximum performance.